# Is there a name for a cycle without subcycles

Tags: graph-theory

My question is quite simple and is in the title:
Is there a name for a cycle without subcycles (in directed graph)?

For my research (in economics, not math, but I need these tools) I am interested in those objects, and I was wondering if they have a specific name? I know it is not elementary nor simple cycles.

Here is a example of what I mean:
I have a a graph with the following edges:

- a->b
- b->c
- c->d
- d->a
- c->a

There are two cycles here:

- abcda
- abca

Here I would like to know what would be the name of a cycle without inside cycles, that is, the cycle abca?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This is variously called **simple cycle, circle, circuit**, or **polygon.** See the [Wikipedia article on cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28graph_theory%29).

A polynomial algorithm for finding mininum circuits in directed graphs was given by Itai and Rodel, SIAM J. Computing 1978.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although it is actually not what I wanted. The wikipedia links provided my the answer: the name I was looking for is **induced cycle**. For whatever reason, I have not read that one.

Comment: @Elias - that concept ought to be close to that of a minimal circuit.